# human readble number output than 3.1223E+10

Tags: sql

How can I get a human readable number instead of `3.1223E+10` in below output?

```
SQL> select file_name, bytes, autoextensible, maxbytes from
dba_data_files where tablespace_name='ATL_DB';
2
FILE_NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
BYTES AUT MAXBYTES
---------- --- ----------
/d/db/oradata/atl/atl_db02.dbf
3.1223E+10 YES 3.2212E+10
```

Thank You!

Answer (score 2):

Try this setting:

```
 set numwidth 20 ;
 select ....
```